# Babel and child class of EventTarget

Tags: webpack, babeljs, dom-events, babel-loader

I have the following exported JS class for a WebGL program:

```
export default class MyClass extends EventTarget {
  constructor(gl) {
    super();
    // more code here
  }
}
```

Babel (`babel-preset-es2015`) generates the following code in the webpack JS bundle:

```
var MyClass = function(_EventTarget) {
  _inherits(MyClass, _EventTarget);

  function MyClass(gl) {
    _classCallCheck(this, MyClass);
    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, 
                  (MyClass.__proto__ || 
                   Object.getPrototypeOf(MyClass)).call(this)); // ***
    // more code here
  }
};
```

At runtime, I get the following error from the `.call(this)` invocation marked with `***` above.

```
TypeError: Failed to construct 'EventTarget': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

I initially assumed that this is a Webpack-related problem, but after more research, I now believe that this error relates to how Babel transpiles my code.

What options should I enable in `babel-preset-es2015` or should I use a different babel plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to my own problem by adding an npm module `event-target-shim` to my project and changed the class by adding the following import:

```
import { EventTarget } from 'event-target-shim';

export default class MyClass extends EventTarget {
  /* same as above */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that maybe the problem was that you didn't import the EventTarget from 'events' in your own class.

So you need import events like this:

```
import EventTarget from 'events';

export default class MyClass extends EventTarget {
  constructor(gl) {
    super();
    // more code here
  }
}
```

I had the same problem on my code and googling I got to this post.
The thing is that on browsers (without babel), you don't need to do the import, but when I run my jest test it crashes because I was using babel so doing the import will do the trick ;), no need to install npm module

Comment: Just to note: `events` refers to [this](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) here you are basically renaming the node `EventEmitter` to `EventTarget` however this is different to [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) i.e. you need to use methods like `on` and `emit` rather than `addEventListener` and `dispatchEvent` but (from what I've seen) exposing the node events library to the client doesn't seem to be causing any obvious issues